# Ensure HDD Mounts Before Program Attempts To Execute

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem, google-drive

I'm using the Google Drive Ubuntu client called overGrive. I have a 1TB HDD that I want to download all of my Google cloud data to.

The issue that I'm running into is that overGrive fails to start if the hard drive isn't mounted. It tries to do the first time setup. I cannot seem to get the hard drive to mount before my startup programs are executed, however, and it never wants to stay mounted once I've mounted it. It goes into a sleep mode and I need to click on the drive in Dolphin to get it to wake up again.

Here's the setup for the drive:

[image: The drive settings]

This is a single 500 GB ext4 partition on the drive. The other half is allocated to my Windows 10 installation and should not be mounted.

What can I do to fix this? I want to ensure that the drive always mounts at system startup, that it does so before my autostart programs, and that it stays mounted as long as the system stays active.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Have you tried `fstab` (file system table) to mount it?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 running KDE Plasma. Does KDE's disk utility not make use of fstab?